# In Mongodb, how can I search for documents using two "aligned" arrays of search parameters?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose you have a mongo document with a composite key made up of two fields:
**doc_id** and **sec_id**

In my business logic, they concatenate to create an "id", where:

> id = doc_id-sec_id.

My query contains these two arrays:

doc_ids = [1,2,3]
sec_ids = [111,222,333]

They correspond to documents with ids: 1-111,2-222, 3-333.

I want to pass these two arrays to a mongo search query so that the search will only return a document where there is a match on id = "doc_ids[ i ]-sec_ids[ i ]".

for example, I want the three documents listed above.  I don't want a document that has an id of say 1-222, or 3-111, etc.

Here is my use of Mongo's C# filter builder to attempt this query.  Would this be a wise query to achieve my goal?  (Specifically the use of the "In")

```
GetDocumentIdsFilter(IEnumerable<string> doc_ids, IEnumerable<string> sec_ids )
{
                   var filterBuilder = Builders<ViewedContent>.Filter;
                   return filterBuilder.And(
                        filterBuilder.In(x => x.doc_id, doc_ids),
                        filterBuilder.In(x => x.sec_id, sec_ids));
}
```

Comment: I don't have the real answer ready for you yet. However, what you're doing is certainly incorrect just now since your effectively asking for all documents where two independent conditions are both true. You're missing the index aspect of the two arrays. With this query in place you _will_ actually get the documents that you don't want...

Comment: Is there there a way I can do a "foreach" here with this zipped array?  Where for each pair of sec_id and doc_id, the query would return a match on sec_id = array.sec_id AND doc_id = array.doc_id

Comment: Not sure I understand... My answer below should do exactly that?!

Comment: Actually I believe you're right.  My last question for you is how can I adjust this filter if there is also a common parameter value for all documents, like a user_id?  Like suppose in the GetDocumentIdsFilter, I also pass a user_id.  How can I chain that on to my filter definition, using an And?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# version that should work:

```
private static FilterDefinition<ViewedContent> GetDocumentIdsFilter(IEnumerable<string> doc_ids, IEnumerable<string> sec_ids)
{
    var filterBuilder = Builders<ViewedContent>.Filter;
    var query = filterBuilder.Or(doc_ids.Zip(sec_ids, (docId, secId) => filterBuilder.And(
        filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.doc_id, docId),
        filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.sec_id, secId))));

    // add another independent filter as per your comment above
    query = filterBuilder.And(query, filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.user_id, "some id"));
    return query;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful and it worked, thank you very much.